# Выводится ерунда Toast.makeText (Java)

Tags: java, android

Входные данные

String s = "5.2";

```
<string name="Copied_activity3">   Copied to the selling price</string>
```

Выводиться ерунда  63453325.2  а должно быть
(Copied to the selling price 5.2)

В чем проблема

```
 Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this,(R.string.Copied_activity3)+ (s), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.Copied_activity3) + " " + s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Спасибо , а в чем  была проблема?

Comment: @Дмитрий: makeText просит тип CharSequence . R.string.Copied_activity3 это  статическая целочисленная переменная

Comment: @Дмитрий: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html?hl=RU